# SSH Config - Extracting a substring from the %h token in Unix, Linux, and Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-config

I have two different environments (production and develop) that both contain a box that have the same local DNS record ie: `foo.example.com`.

I would like to make an entry in my SSH Config similar to the following so that I can just use a wildcard to catch all the different service names and have it magically resolve to the proper DNS record. (Ignore the part that this will have issues with the `known_hosts` file, and the lack of `ProxyJump` related stuff)

```
Host *.prod *.dev
  HostName %h.example.com
```

This way I can just do `ssh foo.dev` or `ssh foo.prod` and as long as the local DNS record exists for those entries, it should just work. However, doing it this way with the `%h` it includes the ending portion from the `Host`, as in, it ends up getting resolved to `foo.dev.example.com` and not `foo.example.com`. I'd much rather do it this way so I don't need to create specific entries for every box in each environment in the SSH Config file, but instead just need to update DNS records in each environment when needed.

I have a feeling that the `Match` keyword is what I want to do to extract the name before the `.`, but I need it to work in Unix, Linux, and in Windows so solutions using tools like `sed` won't work.

I've tried to follow along with [the man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5), but without success. And my google-foo is failing me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve just that by using [ProxyCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand).

Depending on how you want to scale this out (growing number of applications and / or environments) there can be a better alternative. Though with the information you gave, I would proceed like so

```
Host *.prod *.dev
    ProxyCommand ssh `echo %h | cut -d. -f1`
    [...] # Your other configurations
```

More information can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/775726/how-to-set-ssh-config-to-grab-part-of-ssh-hostname-and-use-as-variable)